# Mi proyecto Laravel no me detecta mi componente Vuex

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

estoy haciendo un componente Vuex (**PropuestaStore.js**) que os muestro a continuación:

```
export default {

    state: {

       category: []

    },

    getters: {

       getCategoryFormGetters(state){ //take parameter state

          return state.category
       }
    },

    actions: {
       allCategoryFromDatabase(context){

          axios.get("api/category")

               .then((response)=>{
                  console.log(response.data.categories)
                  context.commit("categories",response.data.categories) //categories will be run from mutation

               })

               .catch(()=>{

                  console.log("Error........")

               })
       }
    },

    mutations: {
       categories(state,data) {
          return state.category = data
       }
    }
}
```

Y mi **app.js** esta de la siguiente manera:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


//support vuex
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

import PropuestaStore from "Store/PropuestaStore"

const store = new Vuex.Store(
    PropuestaStore
 );

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('propuesta-crud', require('./components/Propuesta/PropuestaCRUD.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});
```

El problema parace estar aqui (*fragmento del codigo anterior*):

```
import PropuestaStore from "Store/PropuestaStore"

const store = new Vuex.Store(
    PropuestaStore
 );
```

El codigo dde error es el siguiente :

```
app.js:51120 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'PropuestaStore'
    at webpackMissingModule (app.js:51120)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:51120)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:51293)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87
```

Me esta diciendo que no encuentra el modulo vuex que he creado, yo lo he creado en este directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: PropuestaSotre tambien tiene que ser un modulo vue... no un js

Comment: @gbianchi lo he probado de las dos maneras y no lo pilla

Comment: tiene que ser .vue.. y tal vez la ruta esta mal? fijate de sacarlo al raiz, y luego verificar como escribis la ruta.. no es ./store?

Comment: El directorio Store está dentro del directorio components? Si es así tienes mas el path en `import PropuestaStore from "Store/PropuestaStore`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  ya lo he corregido, era : ** import PropuestaStore from "./components/Store/PropuestaStore"**